# No sound from Scamp using streamlit

Tags: python, audio, streamlit, playback

I'm trying to run a simple code to playback sound on streamlit. This works in my local machine, but I can't get it to work after deploying it to the streamlit app. I'm using a python package called SCAMP to playback the sound.

Below is the python code. I've included 'scamp'  and 'scamp-extensions' to my 'requirements.txt' file. I also included 'scamp' and 'fluidsynth' to 'packages.txt' file.

```
from scamp import *
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title = "streamlit and scamp", page_icon = ":tdata:")
st.subheader("chekc check :wave:")
st.title("streamlit and scamp")

s = Session()
s.tempo = 120

piano = s.new_part("piano")
c2 = [36,38,40,41,43,41,40,38,36]

for note in c2:`
    piano.play_note(note, 0.8, 1)
```

some of the errors I see on the log are:
fluidsynth: error: Error opening ALSA sequencer
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such fil
fluidsynth: error: Couldn't find the requested audio driver 'portaudio'.
fluidsynth: This build of fluidsynth supports the following audio drivers: alsa, file, jack, oss, pulseaudio, sdl2